# what can be php script to Redirect visitors of a wapsite based on Multi Respected Referrer

Tags: php, redirect, referer

I am trying to redirect Visitors to a site based on their referrer url.

Visitors coming from "x" should be redirected to "x1"
and
Visitors coming from "y" should be redirected to "y1"
and so on....

Here x and y are any website url(SOURCE) & x1 and y1 are also website url but these are DESTINATION..

i am trying to do the same with below written but its not working...

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("/site1.com/",$referrer)) {
header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/page-site1.html');
exit;
};
?>
```

Comment: How are you trying that? What's the problem?

Comment: can u make a script for the work i asked please...thankx in advanced...i can not find my answer at the page u provided

Comment: can anyone give me the full script please...i am very new and it is my urgent requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a page x.php which is in the server and y.php which a particular user is comming from.

Code for y.php

```
    <?php

     <a href="x.php">go to x</a>
    ?>
```

Code for x.php

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){//checking if user comming from other page or came here directly

       $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }

//now the $referer holds path of y page
//now you can use it to redirect

    if(//some condition){
      heder('Location:'.$referer);

    }

?>
```

Comment: lets, i want to redirect the users coming from site1 to site2 and site3 to site4...

Comment: you need to use the if condition if($referer=="site1"){header('Location: site2');}

Answer (score 2):

You can use to get the referrer

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

and to redirect:

```
header('location: http://...')
```

Comment: full php code with starting and ending tag...sorry but i dont know php

Comment: It's impossible if we don't know what does "x1" mean, I'm not a mind reader :)

Comment: x1 and y1 are the destination url...

Comment: sorry for incomplete question and bad english...thankx for trying to help me...